# How to create table using PEAR with PHP?

Tags: php, pear

Hi I am using following code to display the table but it shows the error like this.

```
Warning: require(HTML/Table.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aspire/public_html/table.php on line 3

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'HTML/Table.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/aspire/public_html/table.php on line 3
```

This is my code. Can anyone tell me what mistake I did.

```
 require("HTML/Table.php");
 $tableStyle = array("bgcolor"=>"#FFFFFF", "border"=>"1", "width"=>"150",   "cellpadding"=>"1", "cellspacing"=>"2"); 
 $colA = array("field 1", "field 2", "field 3", "", "<b>TOTAL</b>");
 $a = 10;
 $b = 15;
 $c = 8;
 $total = $a+$b+$c;
 $colB = array($a, $b, $c, "", "<b>".$total."</b>");
 $table = new HTML_Table($tableStyle);
 $table->addCol($colA);
 $table->addCol($colB);
 $table->display();
```

Using this "**php go-pear.phar**" command I found the following path.

```
Current include path           : .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
Configured directory           : /home/aspire/pear/share/pear
Currently used php.ini (guess) : /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

So when specify the path before start my code like

```
 include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/";
```

it shows the error like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/aspire/public_html/table.php on line 2
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: This reference is handling the error messages you encounter: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) - it might be useful so that you can do some basic troubleshooting with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Trying your sample code, I got the error message:

```
PHP Warning:  require(HTML/Table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dylan/Desktop/scratch/pear_path.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'HTML/Table.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/dylan/Desktop/scratch/pear_path.php on line 3
```

I resolved this and the program appears to work fine after doing:

```
sudo pear install HTML_Table
```

If you're having issues package versions you might try the pear force option.

```
sudo pear install -f --alldeps HTML_Table
```

I found this here:
http://grokbase.com/p/php/pear-general/05ak6rnj7m/pear-problem-installing-db-dataobject-formbuilder-frontend

Comment: Hi Ddoxey When I using the your comment it shows the No releases available for package "pear.php.net/HTML_Table"
install failed

Comment: That might be related to the version of PHP your using. When I installed I got this message: WARNING: "pear/HTML_Common" is deprecated in favor of "pear/HTML_Common2"

Comment: Ddoxey still shows No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/HTML_Table" Error.

Comment: You might have some luck if you clear the pear cache and try again. I'm not sure. sudo rm /tmp/pear/cache/*

Comment: It shows cannot remove `/tmp/pear/cache/*': No such file or directory

Comment: I think you need a new question: How to do pear install HTML_Table?

Comment: Ok ddoxey I post this question Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set the include path is:

```
set_include_path(".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/");
```

Comment: Ok Include path based on your suggestion but it still shows Warning: require(/HTML/Table.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aspire/public_html/table.php on line 3

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/HTML/Table.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/aspire/public_html/table.php on line 3

Comment: Get rid of the `/` at the beginning, it should be `require("HTML/Table.php");`. Where is the PEAR library actually installed on your server?